# Protractor> TypeError: item.element is not a function

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor, automated-tests

I'm working on an ecommerce project on protractor and I can't honestly figure out what went wrong  with the IT case. I got the following error

```
Failed: item.element is not a function[0m
  Stack:
    TypeError: item.element is not a function
```

I've been pulling my hair out for the last day but the console isn't clear about the specific problem. Cause I've checked and can't see the issue.

**Question:  what is this?  How do I fix this?**

The code from the course is as messy as hell, so I will tidy it up for you.

**code**

describe('Ecommerce Angular Project', function () {

```
it('Customer Shopping cart', function () {
    // write your code here!!!

  function selectItem(product) {
      //chain the locators so that you can pick a specific item regardless of where it is located

      element.all(by.tagName("app-card")).then(function (item) {

          item.element(by.css("h4 a")).getText().then(function (text) {

              if (text == "Samsung Note 8") {
                  // add to cart button if loop is correct. 
                  item.element(By.css("button[class*='btn-info']")).click();                           
              } //end of if Loop 


          })//END: this promise add to cart button for samsung

      })//end of command to find samsung 8

  }

  it('Customer registration', function () {
      // write your code here!!!

      //Scenario 3:  Go Shop page and add items to shopping cart

      //Given I am on the home page
      //when I select the shop link 
      //Then I am taken to the shop page
      //When I am in the shop page I select a mobile phone
      //Then the shopping cart  will show 1 item added
      //When I add another mobile phone to the shopping cart 
      //Then the shopping cart  will show 2 items added

      element(by.linkText("Shop")).click();

      //Select 2 items for shopping cart

      selectItem("Samsung Note 8");
      selectItem("iphone X");

      // I want to display the results and confirm there are only 2 items in the shopping cart
      element(by.partialLinkText("Checkout")).getText().then(function (text) {

          // I want to show both items in the console on a separate line confirm that it 2 items
          var res = text.split("(");
          expect(res[1].trim().charAt(0)).toBe("2");

      })//END: this function will display items in console from shopping bag

  })    //end of customer registration & shopping  it block 
})//end of describe block
```

**Message from console**

(note there were IT cases in this spec file and they passed but once, so ignore those message, but when came the IT scenario that's were things went very wrong)

```
(node:10145) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[16:34:32] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:34:32] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
Started
[16:34:36] W/element - more than one element found for locator By(css selector, *[name="name"]) - the first result will be used
×
Success! The Form has been submitted successfully!.
[16:34:37] W/element - more than one element found for locator By(css selector, *[name="name"]) - the first result will be used
[16:34:37] W/element - more than one element found for locator By(css selector, *[name="name"]) - the first result will be used
Name should be at least 2 characters
[31mF[0m

Failures:
1) Ecommerce Angular Project Customer registration
  Message:
[31m    Failed: item.element is not a function[0m
  Stack:
    TypeError: item.element is not a function
        at /Users/xxx/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/ecommerceAutomation.js:10:12
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/Users/xxx/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1376:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/xxx/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/xxx/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
        at asyncRun (/Users/xxx/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2927:27)
        at /Users/xxx/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
        at <anonymous>
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    From: Task: Run it("Customer registration") in control flow
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/Users/xxx/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:19)
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/xxx/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/ecommerceAutomation.js:27:2)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxx/Documents/JSworkspace/LocatorTraining/ecommerceAutomation.js:1:63)
        at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 3.801 seconds

[16:34:38] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[16:34:38] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[16:34:38] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[16:34:38] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Comment: Did you `console.log(item)` and `console.log(item.element)`, if you did then do share logs. And it's so clear that you are trying to call function `element`, which is not a function. like `var data = 10;` and then call `data();` this will give me same error.

Comment: No, I wasn't able to console.log(item).  I don't think the code got that far

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here `element.all(by.tagName("app-card")).then(function (item) {})`.If you want to get ALL elements with `text=="Samsung Note 8"`then youre missing filter.Thus youll have `element.all(by.tagName("app-card")).filter(function (item) {return item.element(by.css("h4 a")).gettext().then(function(text){return text==="Samsung Note 8"})})`.its return you an array of elements that satisfy this requirement. But if you're looking for just one item then why don't you use `element(by.tagName("app-card")).element(by.cssContainingText("h4 a","Samsung Note 8"))`

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov  thank you  so much.   Sergy I totally agree when I was going through the course material, I didn't understand WHY we why samsung was still in the 'function' either I thought that should have kept blank to lay open the possibility that other items could be used in the array.   But Yong kindly provided the answer for me and I tried his code and it works perfectly.  I'm going to reverse engineer this code and use it the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element.all()` returns `ElementArrayFinder`, you can think it as an array of element.  Therefore the `item` in the `then()` represents an array, rather than a single element.

```
element.all(by.tagName("app-card")).then(function (item) {
    item.element(...)
    ...
})
```

You can't call `.element()` on an `array` object.  But you can call `.element()` on single element as following:

```
element.all(by.tagName("app-card")).then(function (items) {
    items[0].element(...) // items[0] is single element.
    ...
})
```

For your case, the function `selectItem` should change as following:

```
function selectItem(product) {
    //chain the locators so that you can pick a specific item regardless of where it is located

    element.all(by.tagName("app-card")).filter(function(item){
        return item.element(by.css("h4 a")).getText().then(function(txt){
            return txt === product;
        });
    }).then(function(items){
        if(items.length > 0) {
            items[0].element(by.css("button[class*='btn-info']")).click();
        }
        else {
            console.error('Not find product: ' + product);
        }
    }).catch(function(err){
       console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. I'm still in the learning process with protractor. Your answer is slighting confusing to me. Are you saying that I can't use element.all() in this instance and that I should use .element() instead?   Is that right or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: You can use element.all() in your case,  my key point is `element.all().then(function(item){ // the item at here is an array, in javascript Array object has no such element() function , this is why you get error "item.element is not a function" })`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So what should I do to fix this?  Tell me in the most basic way possible. How do I fix this bit of code so that it will work.

Comment: You can't understand my answer?  I have show the fix code in my answer `element.all(by.tagName("app-card")).then(function (items) {
    items[0].element(...) // items[0] is single element.
    ...
})`

Comment: Firstly I want to thank you for helping  me with this question.I am a still learning about using protractor and my understanding that you had given me the answer did not jump out at me as quickly as I would have  liked.  I appreciate your response.

Comment: I just ran your modified code.It works perfectly.   I also understand FINALLY what you were trying to say.  Thanks a million man.   I really appreciate it.